# What is correct C# code for Post-request

Tags: c#, http-post

I'm trying to repead browser Post-request using C# but till now my C# code does not give expected result.
What the correct code should be?

Some info from Firebug about request.
**Headers**:

```
Host:"test-url:8080"
User-Agent:"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:51.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/51.0"
Accept:"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8"
Accept-Language:"ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3"
Accept-Encoding:"gzip, deflate"
Referer:"http://test-url:8080/Emul/report.jsp?type=1"
Cookie:"JSESSIONID=31DF4BFA5ECA4014EE091774D0719AC0"
Connection:"keep-alive"
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests:"1"
```

**Params**:

```
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------1987383936223
Content-Length: 5641

-----------------------------1987383936223
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="type"

1
-----------------------------1987383936223
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="409474.xml"
Content-Type: text/xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<prequest>
 ...
</prequest>
-----------------------------1987383936223
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="upload"

Upload
-----------------------------1987383936223--
```

My C#-code

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http:/test-url:8080/Emul/report.jsp");
// here prequest-xml is contained
            var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\NBCH\1.xml");

            request.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
            request.KeepAlive = true;
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.ContentType = "text/xml; encoding='utf-8'";
            Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();

            requestStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            requestStream.Close();
            HttpWebResponse response;
            response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to check the difference between browser and c# request.